# Understanding the difference between = and =~ operators in bash [[ ]]

Tags: regex, bash

1. `if [[ 23ab = *ab ]] ; then echo yes; fi`

   Is the above code a regular expression?

   Please see the following:
2. `if [[ 23ab =~ [0-9]{1,2}ab ]] ; then echo yes; fi`

So which line is a regex? If the first line is not a regex, why does it work when we are using *?
If it is, but when we instead of `=~` just using `=`, like
`if [[ 23ab = [0-9]{1,2}ab ]]`, it doesn't work right now.

Can you explain the difference between the two lines?

Comment: I presume you're asking about "bash" here; there are several different shells that run on Linux, and it's better to be clear about just which one you're asking about. (POSIX sh does not support `[[ ]]`, so it's clearly not a pure-POSIX shell such as ash or dash... but you could, in theory, be asking about ksh, or zsh, or others as well).

Comment: For simplicity you can use this syntax: `[[ 23ab = *ab ]] && echo "yes"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[[ $a =~ $b ]]` is a regular expression match. In this syntax, `*` matches 0-n instances of the immediately preceding character or pattern.

`[[ $a = $b ]]` is a glob-style pattern match. In this syntax, `*` matches 0-n characters of any type.

Note that it is important that regular expressions in bash be stored in variables. That is:

```
re='[0-9]{1,2}ab'
[[ $foo =~ $re ]]
```

may actually be different from

```
[[ $foo =~ [0-9]{1,2}ab ]]
```

...depending on which version of bash you're running. Always using a variable will prevent this from causing problems.

Note that these are both different from

```
re='[0-9]{1,2}ab'
[[ $foo =~ "$re" ]] ## <- LITERAL SUBSTRING MATCH _NOT_ REGULAR EXPRESSION MATCH
```

...in which case the quoting makes the contents of `$re` literal, ie. *not* treated like a regular expression in modern bash.

Comment: Hi Charles,
Thank you very much! one more question, Is the regex must be put on the right side, I mean:[[ $foo =~ [0-9]{1,2}ab ]]  is correct! 
but [[ [0-9]{1,2}ab =~ $foo ]] is wrong, right?

Comment: @Jack Correct; the pattern or regex may only be on the right-hand side.